# Lightweight C but NO C++ compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm helping out my friend with a project and I'm decent C++ programmer, but they need program done in C. As far as I saw, when you open project in Visual Studio/Netbeans it says C/C++. C++ part is bad because I want compiler to say "i don't get it" if I write

```
class SumStuff {
    ...
```

I'm very used to C++ and I may write something that my friend's lecturer might say "this is not a valid C construct"

Any good/lightweight windows compilers?

Comment: Can't you simply deactivate C++ support ? Or juste create .c files, they will be compiled as C and the compiler should at least emit some warnings

Comment: Most compilers go by the file extension what type of source it is. `.c` for C and `.cpp` or similar for C++.

Comment: I didn't know that, hope this works!

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that Visual Studio's C compiler is very out-of-date and still does not even support C99, so you'll need to stick to C89, e.g. all variables need to be defined before the first statement in a block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say:

http://bellard.org/tcc/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler

It can also work as an interpreter.

Comment: great answer, already working with tcc!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Visual Studio, but gcc has a flag to switch to a different standard. Use `-std=c99`, ideally with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, to have gcc only compile valid C99 (or at least warn about questionable constructs).

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Visual Studio, create the file with extension `.c` and take its `Properties` in Visual Studio. Under `Configuration Properties`, select `C/C++`, then select `Advanced` and in `Advanced` options, change the `Compile as` option to `Compile as C Code (/TC)`. Thats all you need.